# Why might Gutenberg Block Manager be empty

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying hide Gutenberg blocks that are not currently needed.  It seems the block manager is the right way to do that, but when I open it from the settings menu on my page, it is empty.  I don't see any blocks or categories listed.

I did not find any console or network errors either.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What code in your plugin or javascript file are you using to remove/unregister the blocks?

Comment: @S.Walsh I am not using any extra plugin or javascript that was causing the issue, but I did find a function in the theme that called the 'allowed_block_types' hook, and even though the function it fired was empty, this seems to have been causing the issue. So thanks for the suggestion.  I have upvoted your comment